# asyncio : asynchronous program is slower than synchronous one

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, primes, palindrome

The program I wrote loop through a range and find numbers that are prime and palindrome.
As a part of learning asyncio I tried to re-construct it using async. But the result was not good.Here async code is taking much longer that the synchronous code.

> synchronous code

```
import math
import time


def prime(n):
    limit=int(math.sqrt(n))
    for j in range(2,limit):
        if(n%j==0):
            return 0
    return 1


def pallindrome(n):
    n=str(n)
    m=n[::-1]
    if(m==n):
        return 1
    return  0


a, b, c = 999999999, 9999999, 0
start = time.time()

for i in range(a, b, -1): 
    if(pallindrome(i)):  
        if(prime(i)):
            c+=1
            print(i)
    if(c==20):
        break
print("took --> ", time.time()-start)
```

RESULT :

```
999727999
999686999
999676999
999565999
999454999
999434999
999272999
999212999
999070999
998979899
998939899
998898899
998757899
998666899
998565899
998333899
998282899
998202899
998171899
998121899
took -->  0.6525201797485352
```

> asynchronous code

```
import math , time, asyncio

async def is_prime(n):
    limit= int(math.sqrt(n))
    for j in range(2,limit):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        if(n%j==0):
            return 0
    return 1

async def is_pallindrome(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    n=str(n)
    m=n[::-1]
    if(m==n):
        return 1
    return  0

async def waiting(start):
    while True:
        print("processing --> time took {:.2f} --> still running".format(time.time()-start))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
    
async def main():
    a, b, c = 999999999, 9999999, 0
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(a, b , -1):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        if(await is_pallindrome(i)):  
            if(await is_prime(i)):
                c+=1
                print(i)
        if(c==20):
            break
    print(f"Found {c} results in {time.time()-start}s exiting now")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(waiting(time.time()))
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

RESULT:

```
999727999
999686999
999676999
999565999
999454999
999434999
999272999
999212999
999070999
998979899
998939899
998898899
998757899
998666899
998565899
998333899
998282899
998202899
998171899
998121899
Found 20 results in 18.48567509651184s exiting now
```

another interesting thing is that passing `loop.set_debug(True)` and running the code tooks
103 seconds to complete.

can someone explain why this happen?

Comment: asyncio doesn't make things run *in parallel*. It's still only one thing running at a time, but now you're also introducing the overhead of an event loop.

Comment: where do you create tasks to have parallel execution ? Anyway to create a task need time, to save time each task must need enough time to execute

Comment: @AlenPaulVarghese on my PI4 synchronous way 3.4 sec and asynchronous way 163.7 sec ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Your use case seem to be CPU intensive only, and does not require IO work.

Async in python is mainly used to keep using the CPU, while IO operations are running (http request, file writing)

I think that you might be confused with threading. Python can only use one CPU core at a time, and async jobs are queued and executed by the same core. This means that in your example, you will not gain anything by using async, but maybe add some overhead that will slow your execution time.

Comment: note that accessing local files tends to be fast enough that overheads associated with async aren't normally worth it either